# Explanation of map functions (using foldr) in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to define the map function using foldr

I have found the two following solutions, however I'm not quite sure how they are working.

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map' f = foldr ((:) . f) []
```

```
map'' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map'' f  = foldr (\x xs -> f x : xs) []
```

I'm quite new to Haskell and foldr, so I'm struggling to understand what `((:) . f)` in the first solution and what `(\x xs -> f x : xs)` in the second solution do.

I also don't get how foldr is able handle the empty list case.

It would be much appreciated if I could get a simple step by step explanation of this, in layman's terms.

Comment: `(:) . f` and `\x xs -> f x : xs` are eta equivalent.

Comment: The expression `\x xs -> f x : xs` is a [lambda expression](https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function), and `(:) . f` is the [pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) version of it.

Comment: `\x xs -> f x : xs == \x xs -> (:) (f x) xs == \x -> (:) (f x) == (:) . f`.

Comment: do you understand what does `(:)` do? or `.`? or what is lambda expression? or what is lambda function? these are all really prerequisites to this question. try asking one question at a time. then there's the [tag:foldr] tag. try exploring it. there's also a page on Wikipedia. try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info for resources for learning Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

Both `(\x xs -> f x : xs)` and `(:) . f` mean the same thing. They're both functions that take two arguments, apply `f` to the first argument, and then cons that onto the second argument.

So what does `foldr` do when given an empty list? It simply returns the starting value, which in these examples is `[]`.

Here is the implementation of `foldr` from [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr):

```
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

Comment: in (\x xs -> f x : xs) [ ] how does that take two arguments if its only being provided the empty list as the starting value? will x become [ ]? where do you get xs from?

Comment: Actually, `(\x xs -> f x : xs)` is not being provided any arguments here. It's being provided _as an argument_ to `foldr`, which invokes it later. I've edited the answer to quote the implementation of `foldr`, which may help you. The lambda ends up being the function `k` within the definition of `foldr`.

Comment: It might be worth changing to the simpler definition of `foldr`. That more complex one works better with how ghc optimizes things, but involving an extra definition makes it harder to keep everything in your head as a beginner.

Comment: @Carl I think there's a reasonable followup question, "Why is foldr defined this way?" (which I believe has been asked here). But I think it does a disservice to suggest that it is defined in a way that it isn't.

Comment: we don't have to suggest that. we can say it is defined so that the following equality holds: ``foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 ‘f‘ (x2 ‘f‘ ... (xn ‘f‘ z)...)`` (which implies ``foldr f z [] == z``). that's what [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-23100020.3) is doing.